# Vue: this.findxy is not a function at HTMLCanvasElement.eval

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, canvas

It's my error code: this.findxy is not a function at HTMLCanvasElement.eval
Source code:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        this.findxy('move', e); *line throwing error*
    }, false);
```

Function:

```
findxy: function(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
>source code
}}
```

I'm calling .addEventListener as mounted, and i placed function in methods{}, so it should be ok. Anyone could know how to fix this?

Comment: You haven't assigned `findxy` to the canvas property.

Comment: @gorilaami is it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your function as [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), because `this` inside the function is scoped to that function only.

Here is the updated code:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        this.findxy('move', e); *line throwing error*
    }, false);
```

Comment: @gorilaami that's great. You can then accept the answer.